# regular expression using [:punct:] function in java

Tags: java, regex, syntax, pattern-matching

I am using '**punct**' function to replace special characters in a 
String ex: **' REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (colum1, '[[:punct:]]' ), ' ', '')) AS OUPUT '** as part of SQL String in java, But I want particular special character **'-'** not to be replaced? can you suggest best way to do this?

Comment: If you are dealing with ascii strings, Instead of using `[[:punct:]]`, build a character class with the exhaustive list of character. Note that your question is more about SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acc. to [*Character Classes and Bracket Expressions*](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> **‘[:punct:]’**
>   Punctuation characters; in the ‘C’ locale and ASCII character encoding, this is `!` `"` `#` `$` `%` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `-` `.` `/` `:` `;` `<` `=` `>` `?` `@` `[` `\` `]` `^` `_` `\` `{` `|` `}` `~`.

Hence, use

```
[][!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\^_`{|}~]
```

Make sure you escape the `'` correctly in the string literal.

A shortened expression with ranges will look like

```
[!-,.-/:-@[-`{-~]
```

See a [regex test here](https://regex101.com/r/5NyRjB/3) (the `-` is between `,` and `.`, thus you need to use two `!-,.-/` ranges in the above expression to exclude the hyphen).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks for your response, But I am trying to achieve this in SQL ex:DECLARE

colum1 VARCHAR2(20):='ABCD-EFG';
CHARW VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN

CHARW :=REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (colum1, '[[:punc:]' ), ' ', '');

dbms_output.put_line('Printing'||CHARW);

END;

Comment: Great, then use the expression I suggest. Also, note that `[[:punc:]` contains a typo, it must be `[[:punc:]]`. Anyway, atoms cannot be subtracted from POSIX regex patterns (because there is no Java like `[\w&&[^\d]]` or .NET like `[\p{P}-[,]]`), so you need to rewrite it as I show.

Comment: and I don't want  particular character '-' to be deleted in above input SQL i.e,.. 'ABCD-EFG'

Comment: Yes, I see, I forgot to exclude it, I have edited the ranges now. So, this `[][!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\^_\`{|}~]` should work for you. And `[!-,.-/:-@[-\`{-~]` will work for you, too.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried this REPLACE (REGEXP_REPLACE (colum1, '[!/:-@[-`{-~]' ), ' ', '');...it worked but will this expression take care of removing all special characters except particular one  '-'   @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: this [!-,.-/:-@[-`{-~] expression worked perfect and took care of all except '-'....thanks for your help:)  @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since after reaching 15 rep points you obtained the upvoting privilege.